# How does a server handle multiple requests, and how does is know where to send which response?

Tags: node.js, networking, server, tcp, backend

I am trying to figure out how a server handles multiple concurrent requests and each client receive the response to their own request. I did read a few answers online but those confused me even more.

From what I understand a client establishes a TCP connection with the server using a `3-way handshake`, then the client sends a request, and for each request the server gets a thread from the `threadpool`, the `ethernet frame is deencapsulated` to get the request data, each request gets independently processed within its thread, and the response is sent back to the client.

So, is this process correct; if yes, how does the server know which IP to send the response back to since that info gets lost during `deencapsulation`? And what if the server is `single threaded like nodejs`, does each request get its response sequentially? If not, why don't the responses get mixed up?

It would be really helpful if someone could resolve these doubts.
Thanks!